# C#: Is it possible to enumerate BlockingCollection (not its snapshot from when enumerator was requested) without consuming/destroying the elements?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I need to use a kinda-ConsumerProducer pattern (Queue-based), in which the Consumer threads do not in fact consume (destroy) the elements*, but instead a consumer thread can at any point ask for a handle to the beginning of the queue and start enumerating through it at its own speed. I can't use `ConcurrentQueue` because enumerating `ConcurrentQueue` works on its snapshot (taken when `Enumerator` has been requested), so the consumer threads would not see the elements which the producers add in the meantime.

It seemed to me `BlockingCollection` should've been the correct class to use, but it apparently offers only two types of Enumerators/Enumerables:

`GetConsumingEnumerable()`, which

- destroys the elements (calls Dequeue)
- works on the real version of the collection

`BlockingCollection.IEnumerable`, which

- doesn't destroy the elements
- works on the snapshot taken at the moment when Enumerator has been requested

The fact that `BlockingCollection` only offers those two combinations seems too restrictive to be usable in my scenario - I would need something which works on a real queue (like `ConsumingEnumerable` does) but only enumerates the elements without destroying (like `BlockingCollection.IEnumerable` does).

**Question:**

Could anyone advise if there is a way to achieve this **without writing an own Queue implementation** (which obviously I consider a rather discouraged thing to do when we talk about multi-thread environment) - can this be achieved using `BlockingCollection`, or does there exist some other collection that can support such behaviour?

[(*) In fact, one designated of the consumer threads might actually sometimes destroy elements (i.e. call `Dequeue`). However, I am fine if need to say that this action would have to invalidate all the other consumers' ongoing enumerations, so the question can be simplified to assuming that consumers do not `Dequeue` at all.]

Comment: For information BlockingCollection is a facade on top of a IProducerConsumerCollection, and in fact a ConcurrentQueue if you use the default constructor. So your BlockingCollection will have the same limitations as the underlying collection

Comment: As for your precise use-case, I believe you should be able to do by taking a concurrent linked-list and using it as a queue. There's no implementation in the BCL, but there are a few third-party ones available: https://github.com/c7hm4r/LockFreeDoublyLinkedList    Use with caution, I don't know what it's worth performance-wise (or even if it's bug free)

Comment: @KevinGosse [1st comment] I am aware of that, but this sadly doesn't seem to be the answer - as explained in the question I am interested in those functionalities which BlockingCollection adds upon the queue (e.g. GetConsumingEnumerable() is the closest thing I've so far found to - this is something that B.C. adds on top of the functionalities exposed by IProducerConsumer) [2nd comment] Thanks, I'll take a look at it. I thought that's such a standard usecase (basically Consumer/Producer only with several consumers able to consume the same element) that there should be sth in standard lib...?

Comment: Pretty important to understand why it is intentionally crippled.  Enumerating the collection is fundamentally thread-unsafe, the class cannot know when you're done iterating so cannot use a lock to ensure the collection won't change while you're busy.  Making a copy is the only reasonable alternative, but your code must be aware that it very easily turns stale.  Nothing will blow up badly, but your code is likely to malfunction anyway when it munches on old data.  The only *good* alternative is not needing to iterate.

Comment: @hans-passant I am rather confused by this explanation - all the difference between ConcurrentQueue<T> and BlockingCollection(ConcurrentQueue<T> is that the former is crippled in the way you mention, and the latter is not (it provides GetConsumingEnumerable() which does not create a shapshot). All the possible problems that I see (including what you mention, i.e. problems at the end of iterating) are the same whether you'd want to iterate using GetConsumingEnumerable() or standard enumerable, so I am not sure why B.C. would need this kind of crippling. Or did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: GetConsumingEnumerable is always thread-safe.  It uses a lock to safely remove the item from the collection and only the thread that calls it can see the item.  There is no point in fretting over what it does when you know that you don't want to use it.  Making this as plain as possible: if iterating the collection is a hard requirement then using BlockingCollection is a bad idea.  You need to control the locking yourself.